# "was" vs. "had" in "If I 'was'/'had' his age"

Tags: word-choice, subjunctives

> “He is too old. He looks tired. If I was his age I would choose to do the same,” she said.
>
> (The Guardian - http://m.guardian.co.uk/world/2013/feb/28/pope-benedict-xvi-s-last-day-in-office-live-updates)

Is it grammatically correct to say "If I was his age"? I'm not a competent of English language, but, even if I don't know why, I would have said that "If I had his age" is the correct form.

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 10):

It should actually be "If I were his age", but yes, the construction is sound.  I know "have" is used in this way in some other languages--Spanish for example--but in English we don't say "If I had his age".

> When I was your age, we had to walk uphill to school both ways!
>
> Ah, young love.  If I were your age...

The above examples demonstrate the was vs were: *was* is used to talk about something that *did* happen when you were that age.  *were* is used to postulate something that *might happen* if you were that age.

It's just how it's said in English, simple as that :)

Comment: but 'if I had been your age' is correct, right?

Comment: If you are talking about a hypothetical situation in the past, yes.  "If I had been your age when the Beatles were still together, I would have gone to every concert and held up a sign saying 'John Lennon 3:16'."

Comment: @Batman Yup, Hellion's got it right :)

Answer (score 1):

Always say were, never say was or has. :)

Comment: Theta, thank you and stay with us. We are a little community, but are growing rather rapidely. Don't forget to ask, ask, ask!